# Is it possible to generate django models from the database?

Tags: database, django, oracle, orm

I've been messing around with Django and the Django ORM at home, and I've got to say, I feel it is one of the best out there in terms of ease of use.

However, I was wondering if it was possible to use it in "reverse".

Basically what I would like to do is generate Django models from an existing database schema (from a project that doesn't use django and is pretty old).

Is this possible?

**Update:** the database in question is Oracle

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Yes, use the `inspectdb` command:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

> inspectdb
>
> Introspects the database tables in the database pointed-to by the DATABASE_NAME setting and outputs a Django model module (a models.py file) to standard output.
>
> Use this if you have a legacy database with which you'd like to use Django. The script will inspect the database and create a model for each table within it.
>
> As you might expect, the created models will have an attribute for every field in the table. Note that inspectdb has a few special cases in its field-name output:
>
> [...]

Comment: Reading over that info, it says it is supported for mysql, sqlite, and postgresql.    Sadly the database I am trying to use is Oracle :(

Comment: oof, I don't believe Django has good support for Oracle at the moment, both forwards or backwards : /

Comment: Django has almost all the features one could think of. It still amazes me even after years of use.

Comment: I'm not sure but... maybe you should point out that the link refers to the `dev` version (with more emphasize ?? maybe not..)

Comment: is it possible to use same command when new table is inserted

Answer (score 39):

(Django 1.7.1) Simply running `python manage.py inspectdb` will create classes for all tables in database and display on console.

```
 $ python manage.py inspectdb
```

Save this as a file by using standard Unix output redirection:

```
 $ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

(This works for me with mysql and django 1.9)

Answer (score 12):

I have made a reusable app based on django's inspectdb command utility, 
[Django Inspectdb Refactor](https://github.com/farhan0581/django-inspectdb-refactor).

This breaks models into different files inside models folder from a existing database.
This helps managing models when they become large in number.

You can install it via pip:

```
pip install django-inspectdb-refactor
```

Then register the app in settings.py as `inspectdb_refactor`

After this you can use it from command line as :

```
python manage.py inspectdb_refactor --database=your_dbname_defined_in_settings --app=your_app_label
```

This will successfully create models folder with all the tables as different model files inside your app. For example:

[image: typical structure]

More details can be found [here.](https://medium.com/cashify-engineering/generating-django-models-from-a-database-f4d03883cc5b)

Comment: Add some more description here

Comment: python3 manage.py inspectdb_refactor --database=xmldb --app=django_sb_admin   Error: Unknown command: 'inspectdb_refactor'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Comment: did you register this app in your settings.py as **inspectdb_refactor** ?

Comment: I am getting this errror `get_meta() missing 1 required positional argument: 'is_partition'`. Using django 2.0