# Dynamic Django model creation based on existing DB table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to figure out how I can use the type() module to dynamically create a Django model based on existing DB tables without having to either write it out manually or use the manage.py generator to inspect the DB.  Reason is my schema changes frequently -- adding new tables, adding/deleting columns, etc.  Anyone have a good solution?  Something similar to this would be awesome: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179469/is-it-posible-to-generate-django-models-from-the-database

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [inspectdb code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py), and instead of outputting code return classes.