# django create model of unknown table dynamically

Tags: python, django, dynamic, model

I need to create models of existing previously unknown tables.  Others have had [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136371/dynamic-django-model-creation-based-on-existing-db-table) to

> You can look at [inspectdb](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py) code, and instead of outputting code return
>   classes.

but for a python newbie I am having difficulties.  Could anyone offer a more concrete example on how to do this?  Many thanks.

UPDATE: I am exploring [this](http://dynamic-models.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/model.html#topics-model).  Looks v promising. There seem to be several options for creating dynamic models, some of which though require non- mySQL dbs (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577) stackoverflow Q)

UPDATE2: I can now create a model of a previously unknown mysql table at runtime using the below functions. When I try to query the model though, for a table called 'table1' I get "Table 'djangodb.subscription_table1' doesn't exist").  When I rename 'table1' to 'subscription_table1' I get this error: "Table 'djangodb.subscription_subscription_tb2f1e1e47d73417ab2b187bc4a08bf57' doesn't exist").

HELP!

FINAL UPDATE: I went with another solution for my particular problem: [Django - List of Dictionaries to Tables2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366098/django-list-of-dictionaries-to-tables2/14438782#14438782)

```
def getModel(table_name):
    myColumns=getColumns(table_name)


    attrs = {}
    attrs['__module__']  = 'subscription.models'

    for x,y in myColumns.items():
        fieldType = y["type"]
        if x == 'id': ''
        elif   fieldType  == "char":    attrs[x]=models.CharField(max_length='length')
        elif fieldType  == "float":   attrs[x]=models.FloatField(max_length='length')   
        elif fieldType  == "int":     attrs[x]=models.IntegerField()
        elif fieldType  == "text":    attrs[x]=models.TextField()
        else: print "AW PROB in exptDB---------------",x,y["type"],y["length"] 

    myModel = type(str(table_name), (models.Model,), attrs) 



    return myModel




def getColumns(expt_id):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("desc %s;" % (expt_id))
    exptInfo = str(cursor.fetchall())[1:-1]

    myList= exptInfo.split("""(u'""")
    myColumns = {}
    for item in myList:
        mySplit = item.replace("u'","").replace("'","").replace(" ","").split(",")
        if len(mySplit)>=2:  
            subSplit=mySplit[1].split("(")
            if len(subSplit)>=1: 
                subSplit.append('999')#does not latter.  
                myColumns[mySplit[0]]={"type":subSplit[0],"length":subSplit[1].replace(")","")}

    return myColumns
```

Comment: "Previously unknown tables" - what does that mean?

Comment: A table that does not have a model

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `inspectdb` command. It's designed precisely for this kind of situation.

However, you don't need to look at the `inspectdb` code, just read the following page dedicated to this issue: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: I need to create these models at runtime unforunately, for pre-existing but unknown mysql tables.