# How do I go from a MySQLWorkbench EER model (ERD) to Django?

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I designed a database using MySQLWorkbench EER model with many foreign key relationships and tables using Django default naming conventions (like using `id` for primary keys, `*_id` for foreign keys). Now that I feel that I have a good back-end design, how do I *convert* that into a Django Python code for `models.py`? Do I have to manually type out every table?

I read that there is already a [UML to Django](http://code.google.com/p/uml-to-django/) conversation and I also know MySQLWorkbench can export and "Forward Engineer SQL CREATE script". But I'm not sure if MySQLWorkbench can export a UML diagram.

Also another question, I have an `order` table that has 3 foreign keys to the `user` table. The three foreign keys are `user_created`, `user_modified`, and `user_status`. I know that normally Django would create a foreign key called `user_id`, but what if I need three **distinct** foreign key from one table?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179469/is-it-posible-to-generate-django-models-from-the-database. The answer to your question is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you can "Forward Engineer SQL CREATE script" and afterwards proceed as described in this thread: [Is it possible to generate django models from the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179469/is-it-posible-to-generate-django-models-from-the-database)

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming `inspectdb` won't be _smart_ enough to figure out a join table for M-M relationships, but it's a start!

Answer (score 4):

It's an old post, but here is an MySQL Workbench Module to export a Django model.py http://sourceforge.net/p/mysqlworkbenchdjangomodule

Comment: Please don't answer with a link. Links to more information is appreciated, but you should at least summarize the information your trying to give.

Comment: It's an MySQL Workbench Module to export a Django model.py file. What should i say more?